# Query with ->matching() multiple arguments returns empty array in CakePHP4

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I want to show on a page list of news from different facilities. To achieve that i retrieve data from corresponding tables. Also I added a search engine by month and stuck with a matching information from different tables.

I made a next query in my NewsController in CakePHP.

```
            if ($month !== 'all') {
                $query
                ->matching('Schools.NewsMonths', function ($q) use ($month) {
                     return $q->where(['NewsMonths.month' => $month]);
                 })
                 ->matching('Universities.NewsMonths', function ($q) use ($month) {
                     return $q->where(['NewsMonths.month' => $month]);
                 })
                ->matching('Colleges.NewsMonths', function ($q) use ($month) {
                    return $q->where(['NewsMonths.month' => $month]);
                })
            ;}
```

So with that query i can sort information by corresponding month. But when i run query with multiple conditions, it returns an empty array.

When I comment ->matching() and leave only one:

```
            if ($month !== 'all') {
                $query
                ->matching('Schools.NewsMonths', function ($q) use ($month) {
                     return $q->where(['NewsMonths.month' => $month]);
                 })
                //->matching('Universities.NewsMonths', function ($q) use ($month) {
                //    return $q->where(['NewsMonths.month' => $month]);
                //})
                //->matching('Colleges.NewsMonths', function ($q) use ($month) {
                //    return $q->where(['NewsMonths.month' => $month]);
                //})
            ;}
```

query returns array of data with selected month. Is there any way to match data from different tables at once?

Comment: `matching` returns only results where the given query matches. By including three of these, you are asking for only results that match all three. If you want to find anything that matches any one of the three, you might need to do three queries and manually merge the results, or do manual joins and an `or` condition instead of using `matching` or you might reverse the logic, finding NewsMonths that match, and containing the other associations from there. That does significantly change the structure of the data that you get from it, though.